# Codeigniter working directory inside another working directory

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I am working on codeigniter for a while now and have met with an issue.
I use "localhost/controller/function" which is how codeigniter works.
Where controller classes are in controller folder in application.
I have a new codeigniter setup in root folder names "big" with its own controller, view, models etc. How can I run files in "big" like I do for my the original application.
I tried "localhost/big/controller/function", which obviously didn't work.

Please help, I am completely new with codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

just go to index.php of your application (big)

change/add line:

```
$application_folder = "applications/big";
```